Rust Multi-threaded Code: The borrowed value doesn't live long enough
I am doing the  1 Billion Row Challenge (1brc) in Rust and am tired of trying to satisfy the compiler; Basically the code (that is attached at the end) spawns some threads and later joins all of them, compiler is raising an error of outliving the scope of variable definition for a variable that is declared in the scope of main function. My hunk is that the compiler thinks that the threads might outlive the main thread and the borrowed value might get invalid while still borrowed. However, since I am joining all the threads, and after that there is just a main thread that works and the data that is being borrowed is referenced there, so no thread will ever outlive the scope in which the borrowed identifier is defined. Looking for help.
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread::{self, available_parallelism};

fn main() {
    let n_threads = available_parallelism().unwrap().get();

    let datalines = fs::read_to_string("data/measurements.txt").unwrap();
    let lines: Vec<&str> = datalines.lines().collect();

    let n_lines = lines.len();

    let chunk_size = (n_lines + 1) / n_threads;

    let mut handles = Vec::with_capacity(n_threads);

    let data_map: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<&str, [f32; 4]>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    for chunk in lines.chunks(chunk_size) {
        let chunk = chunk.to_vec();
        let data_map = Arc::clone(&data_map);
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for line in chunk {
                let data = &mut data_map.lock().unwrap();
                if let Some((state, temperature)) = line.split_once(';') {
                    let temperature = temperature.parse().unwrap();
                    let entry = data.entry(state).or_insert([-100.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0]);
                    entry[0] = entry[0].min(temperature);
                    entry[1] += temperature;
                    entry[2] = entry[2].max(temperature);
                    entry[3] += 1.0;
                }
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    let outfile = File::create("output.txt").expect("Panicked while opening/creating outfile");
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(outfile);
    let data = data_map.lock().unwrap();

    for (state, stats) in &*data {
        let outline = format!(
            "{}={}/{:.1}/{}, ",
            state,
            stats[0],
            stats[1] / stats[3],
            stats[2]
        );
        writer
            .write_all(outline.as_bytes())
            .expect("Panicked while writing outline");
    }

    writer.flush().expect("Panicked while flushing the output");
}


EDIT: Output of the updated code:
 time cargo run --release                                                                                     in bash at 20:10:47
   Compiling billion-lines-challenge v0.1.0 (/home/abbas-taqvi/rust-projects/1brc-rust-lite)
    Finished `release` profile [optimized] target(s) in 0.17s
     Running `target/release/billion-lines-challenge`
Init and Reading the file took 23
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread has started
Thread has ended
Thread Computation took 42
Writing the outfile took 0

real    1m6.617s
user    0m56.713s
sys     0m10.093s



Use std::thread::scope() and you'll be fine. Then you won't need the Arcs either.

Thanks for the reply. I can't find prompt tutorials on scoped threads other than the official guide which appears a bit tricky to me. More pointers or code edits would be much appreciated

I meant something like this.

Love that, Thankyou, However my new implementation inspired by your prev response takes 66s on my system but your shared example takes 6m55s, The difference being I spawned threads in loop so more should get spawned theoretically which is what we usually want. This is my new code. However I feel that the threads aren't doing this concurrently since the print statements when I add them gets printed sequentially (strictly one threads ends and the other begins); Have a look at the output.

Your code now isn't using threads. The thread::scope needs to go outside the for-loop and within each iteration you need to .spawn using the given scope parameter. The scope call doesn't launch a thread, only the .spawn does. Pay closer attention to @user4815162342's example.

Makes sense, my bad!. However my new implementation in the light of your response still takes 6+ mins where as the one with only main thread (my prev code) and useless thread scope that i defined works in 65s, Any idea why this happens? Is the overhead because of move or what?

Your new implementation is the same link as the previous one, did you paste the wrong link?

Wohooo! a new hunk that I had made the code run in 27s where file reading time is 24s so the code after that runs in 3s. This is the new code. I am now maintaining a local hashmap for each thread to prevent the threads waiting for the lock (making the code sequentially in practical), updating the original Hashmap later. I now need to reduce file reading time

Sorry @FilipeRodrigues for giving prev links, I am not so familiar with Rust playground links, I think I should give links to gists which ensure I get the last updated code.

Congratulations on your progress! The question is likely not relevant at this point, though - if you have more questions, feel free to post a new question rather than editing this one.

Makes sense, However I feel like the question will be marked duplicate since there are already questions for reading file in chunks but none of them have a good answer, there are just naive implementations of guys with disclaimers "Idk if this is efficient but worked for me" etc.
